# Image loading takes more time (15-20) for some countries

Tags: html, performance, web, cordova

Recently I have build a Phonegap App to Swedish company to publish their news. In the App first page, it displays the top 10 news with highlighted image per each. But Users reported that news data loading very fast to them but to load images it is taking 20-30 seconds.

I have tested this with so many devices but for me all the content loading within 3-5 seconds. (Please note: I'm in Sri Lanka and our web server (Windows Server 2008R2 with IIS 7.5) is located in UK)

Did anyone experience this kind of issue before? Could you please let me know any solution to simulate this kind of issue?

Comment: Here are few additional information, 1. I also download the same app (production app) from Google Play and App Store and tested. But for me it is loading within 3-5 second complete page with images 2. Web services sending data with image URL as JSON stream and images are directly displaying using <img> tag in client side. 3. What Swedish users mentioning is they can quickly see the news text(it load very fast) but to load images it takes 15-20 second. Please note, page loading is very fast to them but images.

Answer (score 0):

Likely expected behavior - more requests you need/farther away client from server than page will take longer time to download.

Steps to investigate:

- Run your page through one of may perf tools (like YSlow) to see what is/should be causing it.
- Simulate slower connection speeds (i.e. Fiddler provides estimates as well basic speed manipulation)
- Try using different proxies to access content from different locations.
- Check if there are unnecessary requests
- Check for unnecessary uploads (like huge cookies) or large POST request.

Possibly you need to use CDN to deliver content, but first find what is slow - i.e. if you are making to many requests.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'll check through the suggestion you made. Here are few additional information,

1. I also download the same app (production app) from Google Play and App Store and tested. But for me it is loading within 3-5 second complete page with images
2. Web services sending data with image URL as JSON stream and images are directly displaying using <img> tag in client side.
3. What Swedish users mentioning is they can quickly see the news text(it load very fast) but to load images it takes 15-20 second. I think page loading is very fast to them but images.